# Как заменять текст в консоли c++ без отчистки экрана

Tags: c++

У меня есть переменная с текстом, например,

string a="smth1\nsmth2\smth3\n";

И мне нужно уже выведенный в консоль текст заменить текстом из этой переменной, я пробовал flush и другие методы, но они не помогали, а проблема system("cls") в том, что на экране можно заметить мигание во время между отчисткой экрана и выводом нового сообщения

Comment: возможные [дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C+%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C)